# Kotlin Firestore Timestamp Add Time

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to add time to a `Timestamp` formatted time without having to convert it multiple times?

```kt
      val seconds: Long = Timestamp.now().seconds

      val utcDT = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(seconds, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
      val withTwo: LocalDateTime = utcDT.plusHours(2)
      val date: Date = Date.from(withTwo.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC))
      val new = Timestamp(date)

      Log.d("sirEgghead", "Timestamp: ${Timestamp.now().toDate()}")
      Log.d("sirEgghead", "utcDT: $utcDT")
      Log.d("sirEgghead", "addedTwo: $withTwo")
      Log.d("sirEgghead", "date: ${date.time}")
      Log.d("sirEgghead", "new: ${new.toDate()}")
```

This is the mess that I went through just to add two hours and return it to `Timestamp` format two hours in the future.

```
Timestamp: Wed May 18 21:53:12 EDT 2022
utcDT: 2022-05-19T01:53:12
addedTwo: 2022-05-19T03:53:12
date: 1652932392000
new: Wed May 18 23:53:12 EDT 2022
```

I do not want to use the local system time in case the time on the device is incorrect.  The data is stored in Google Firestore.

Comment: To understand better, do you basically want to increment a timestamp value that exists in a Firestore document by two hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a `LocalDateTime` instance, create an `Instant` instance and add `2` hours to it, using its `plus` method which takes `TemporalUnits` for addition.

```
val seconds: Long = Timestamp.now().seconds
val addedSeconds = Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds).plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS).epochSecond 
val newTimeStamp = Timestamp(addedSeconds, 0)
```